# How to set Windows Spotlight to periodically auto-change the desktop wallpaper in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I've noticed that the lock screen on Windows 11 automatically changes the background image every few hours, when set to **[Windows Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Spotlight)**.
`Settings > Personalization > Lock screen`

[image]

I would like to set the desktop background picture to also automatically change but the only option available is a slideshow of images from folder. The **Windows Spotlight** is not provided as an option :-(
`Settings > Personalization > Background`

[image]

I remember that in Windows 10 there used to be workarounds using `CMD` and `PowerShell` to fix Windows Spotlight issues. Anyone know how to do this on Windows 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmd` and `powershell` macro-scripts you're looking for to reset Windows Spotlight & re-register it are these:

1. open Notepad
2. copy and paste the following (source: [thewindowsclub.com](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-windows-spotlight)) :

```
:: Reset Windows Spotlight

DEL /F /S /Q /A "%USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets"
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings"
    
:: Re-register Windows Spotlight
    
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage *ContentDeliveryManager*).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"
```

3. save as a `.BAT` file
4. execute the file as administrator `Right-click > Run as administrator`

**However,** there is a much better solution - install the **[Dynamic Theme](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dynamic-theme/9nblggh1zbkw)** app for Windows 11 from the Microsoft app store (free). In addition to be able to set Windows Spotlight as your background, you can choose to set the daily spotlight image from Bing as well.

[image]

Comment: You should provide your source for the script. Copying a pasting from an external website is considered plagiarism if you don’t quote and cite your source. It was extremely odd you repeated the same text twice, which is the reason, I went on a mission to locate the source for your script

Comment: upvoted, but please provide the source of the script as Ramhound has requested. it really does mean somthing.

Comment: added code source...

Comment: Ramhound - as requested, I added the source of the code, nevertheless, the text is not repeating twice as you suggested... first line deletes `...\LocalState\Assets`, second deletes `...\Settings`.